# flutter google maps how to search in web

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps

Im doing a flutter web app but there is an issue, whenever I try to search with geolocator or geocoding I get the current error:

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method locationFromAddress on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 308:7
```

I tried other methods but I cant seem to find a method for google maps to make my app be able to search for the google address. Is there any library or way to search from google maps in flutter?

Comment: Hello! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to increase your chances of getting help from the community.